# Change Hyperlink location on browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

Im trying to change where my hyperlink points to on browser resize, however i either block all my links or none of them

```
var $w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;

if ($w > 1025) {
    $('a.something').each(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        location.href = "/products.html";
    });
} else {
    $('a.something').each(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
         location.href = "javascript:void(0);";
    });
}

if ($w > 1025) {
    $('.mainMenu > li').unbind().hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().slideToggle(400);
    });
} else {
    $('.mainMenu > li').unbind().click(function (e) {
        $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().slideToggle(400);
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry cannot understand what you try to achieve and what is wrong? where in your code do you hook up into the resize event? what are those `.something`s -- do they store the hyperlinks? Ideally and if possible prepare [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) that represents your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making multiple DOM changes upon every resize can be expensive and slow your site down. I would suggest making the functionality determine what action to take based on browser size.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href]', function (e) {
    var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;

    if (width < 1025) {
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This will only block links while in a small (below 1025px) view size.

```
$('.mainMenu > li').on('hover click', function () {
    $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().slideToggle(400);
});
```

You can do both bindings at once. If you really need, you can put the same if as above in this block, but I think in most all cases you'll be fine leaving this as-is.

Comment: didnt know i could do both bindings at once, that works out perfectly. As for blocking the links is there a way to change it before the event OR without an event handler? (on the resize) so if (width < 1025) { $('a.something')each(function (e) { e.preventDefault() } ?

Comment: You don't need to change the href attribute at all. The preventDefault will cause the link to take no action, only when in a "mobile" view. Where as in a "desktop" view the link will act normally.

Comment: ok, 3/7 links have submenus, so id like to target only those 3 (they have specific class) to preventDefault() but they still are working :S so far ive gotten all or none to work

Comment: Then you can change the selector. I was using a generic one, but you can augment to suit your needs. Sounds like maybe having it as 'a.something' would work...though that really depends on what class you're using. Or you can do a check, like: $(this).hasClass('something')

Comment: another quick question actually, is there an opposite of preventDefault that you know of that would allow the links to work once resized? When i load the browser at 1025+ and then shrink and (activates prevent default) and then expand again the prevent is still binded i think

Comment: The above functionality is completely dynamic. It will always preventDefault at "mobile" size, and will not preventDefault at "desktop" size, no matter how many times you resize.